# IOTA Reference Implementation—UnsatisfiedLinkError on Windows

Tags: iri-node, windows

1)
When I compile IOTA Reference Implementation 1.4.1.4 from sources on Windows 10 using:

```
git clone https://github.com/iotaledger/iri cd iri mvn clean compile
```

I get:

> [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 7.767 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2017-12-29T11:42:17+02:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 20M/68M

It creates the target directory and the .class files. I need to get the iri.jar file:

Now when I command:

```
mvn package
```

I get next error:

In the all the tests it runs:

> T E S T S ...
>
> <<< ERROR! java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\librocksdbjni16850478755329069913.dll:
>   A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
>
> ...
>
> Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 5, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
>   <<< FAILURE!
>   quietGetTail(com.iota.iri.controllers.BundleViewModelTest) Time
>   elapsed: 0 sec <<< ERROR! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not
>   initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>
> ...
>
> Results :
>
> Tests in error: com.iota.iri.BundleValidatorTest:
>   C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\librocksdbjni13156992591185227005.dll:
>   A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
>   quietGetTail(com.iota.iri.controllers.BundleViewModelTest): Could not
>   initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   fromHash(com.iota.iri.controllers.BundleViewModelTest): Could not
>   initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   getTail(com.iota.iri.controllers.BundleViewModelTest): Could not
>   initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   quietFromHash(com.iota.iri.controllers.BundleViewModelTest): Could not
>   initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   getTransactionViewModels(com.iota.iri.controllers.BundleViewModelTest):
>   Could not initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   initSnapshot(com.iota.iri.controllers.MilestoneViewModelTest): Could
>   not initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   nextGreaterThan(com.iota.iri.controllers.MilestoneViewModelTest):
>   Could not initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   previous(com.iota.iri.controllers.MilestoneViewModelTest): Could not
>   initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   latest(com.iota.iri.controllers.MilestoneViewModelTest): Could not
>   initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   getMilestone(com.iota.iri.controllers.MilestoneViewModelTest): Could
>   not initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   latestSnapshot(com.iota.iri.controllers.MilestoneViewModelTest): Could
>   not initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   firstWithSnapshot(com.iota.iri.controllers.MilestoneViewModelTest):
>   Could not initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   getHash(com.iota.iri.controllers.MilestoneViewModelTest): Could not
>   initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   next(com.iota.iri.controllers.MilestoneViewModelTest): Could not
>   initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   nextWithSnapshot(com.iota.iri.controllers.MilestoneViewModelTest):
>   Could not initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   first(com.iota.iri.controllers.MilestoneViewModelTest): Could not
>   initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   index(com.iota.iri.controllers.MilestoneViewModelTest): Could not
>   initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   store(com.iota.iri.controllers.MilestoneViewModelTest): Could not
>   initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   snapshot(com.iota.iri.controllers.MilestoneViewModelTest): Could not
>   initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   PrevBefore(com.iota.iri.controllers.MilestoneViewModelTest): Could not
>   initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   updateSnapshot(com.iota.iri.controllers.MilestoneViewModelTest): Could
>   not initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   com.iota.iri.controllers.TransactionViewModelTest: Could not
>   initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   com.iota.iri.service.TipsManagerTest: Could not initialize class
>   org.rocksdb.RocksDB get(com.iota.iri.storage.TangleTest): Could not
>   initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   save(com.iota.iri.storage.TangleTest): Could not initialize class
>   org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   getKeysStartingWithValue(com.iota.iri.storage.TangleTest): Could not
>   initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB
>   com.iota.iri.TransactionValidatorTest: Could not initialize class
>   org.rocksdb.RocksDB com.iota.iri.TransactionValidatorTest
>
> Tests run: 100, Failures: 0, Errors: 29, Skipped: 1
>
> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 30.439 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2017-12-29T11:45:19+02:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 22M/74M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test
>   (default-test) on project iri: There are test failures.

So what is wrong with the IOTA Reference Implementation persistence level RocksDB part ? How to remedy this in order to build the .jar ?

I need to build it for Windows. Does anybody have an idea how to fix this ?

2)
Will this error appear in Linux derived platforms, on Ubuntu for example?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the DLL of RocksDB is not found. On Linux or macOS it's working without any problems. On Windows you might need some additional steps. As I have only a Mac the moment to my side, the following steps are not tested.

What you should try:
Download the RocksDB jar referenced in the pom.xml. At the moment of writing it is: [version 5.7.3](http://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.rocksdb/rocksdbjni/5.7.3)

Extract the DLL inside the jar archive and place it in `c:\windows\system32` Another option is to place it somewhere else and set the path at startup with the following parameter: `-Djava.library.path=<path_to_dll>`